# Is "die to it" an acceptable phrase in the UK?

Tags: grammaticality, british-english

I have just been told by a British English speaker that *die to it* is "perfectly correct English". I've never heard this phrase before. His example sentence is:

> You won't **die to** a bee sting, unless you have allergies.

I would use *die of* or *die from* instead. Is his usage also correct?

[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=die+from+it%2Cdie+of+it%2Cdie+to+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdie%20from%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdie%20of%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdie%20to%20it%3B%2Cc0) suggests that it does (or did) exist but is rare.

[A book search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q="die+to+it"&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=mB7QV_zlJsSw0ASz1q7gAQ) seems to show that it's limited to religious use.

Comment: "Die to" makes incidental sense at best in American English.  I could easily figure it out from context but it is not something I have ever heard said. "Die from" is the most correct. "Die of" is also acceptable but to my ears at least, it sounds...lazy I think is the best way to put it. Nevertheless, "die to" might be proper British English.

Comment: @G-Cam: Why would you think *"die to" might be proper British English?* We're not *that* weird! I was about to comment that I think you're more likely to figuratively *die **of** boredom*, whereas you literally *die **from** fatal diseases or wounds*. But [not so](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=die+of+boredom%2Cdie+from+boredom%2Cdie+of+cancer%2Cdie+from+cancer&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdie%20of%20boredom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdie%20from%20boredom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdie%20of%20cancer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdie%20from%20cancer%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: No, I'm a 67-year-old Brit and I'll swear I never heard anyone say "Die to ..."

Comment: @CJ Dennis: The written instances of ***die to it*** seem to all be either non-native speakers, or *very* old usages in the specific religious context of ***to die to sin = to "be dead" to sin = to have no interactions with sin***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you've let slip that even we think we're a *bit* weird!

Comment: @David Garner: The rest of the world is still trying to figure out how we could be so weird as to pull out of Europe! We may plough a lonely furrow, but I've no doubt in the fullness of time we'll reap a good harvest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, at the risk of being chastized for going off topic, I'll just say, That's very poetic, and I really hope you're right.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ngrams shows no usage at all of "die to boredom" and "die to cancer".

Comment: The question is specious, and the usage "die to" is spurious. Perhaps the OP means to say _"I'm **dying to** [verb]."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant How would that possibly work with the example sentence?

Comment: @CJDennis You misunderstand. I meant: _Perhaps the OP means to say that his reported speaker heard "die to" for "dying to."_

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just occurred to me that what the OP's friend heard was something on the order of: _"I would just **die to** be driving that Aston."_ It's an instance of message garbling.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: But OP says his friend actually gave the specific example as cited above. Either that friend is an incredibly incompetent native speaker, or (more likely, imho) when OP says "a British English speaker" he just means someone who speaks English with a British rather than American accent (but nevertheless a non-native speaker, and thus perfectly capable of making a non-idiomatic choice here).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, and the OP's friend created the sentence based upon his misunderstanding of what he heard. Your imho is very likely istm.

Answer (score 5):

We normally say "he died from cancer" or "he died of cancer". We definitely do not say "he died to cancer".

"Die to" is a phrase used in Christian theological discussions, but it is not a substitute for "die from" or "die of". With "die from/of", what follows is the thing that caused death. With "die to", what follows is something that the person is trying to dramatically distance himself from. Like, "We must die to sin", that is, we must separate ourselves from sin as much as we possibly can. The most common use is probably, "die to self", meaning to abandon selfish desires and ego. I can't think of this phrase being used outside of a theological discussion. I've never heard someone say, "I should die to video games" to mean that he plays too many video games and wants to quit!

You might find the words "die to" in a totally different sense, where what follows is a verb and "to" is part of an infinitive. Like, "The soldier died to defend his country."

Answer (score 0):

British English speaker here: "die to" is definitely used in the UK. For exampled "Mr X died to cancer". I believe it is restricted to noun causes of death, as "died to starvation", "died to liver failure" sounds OK, but "died to crushing" or "died to Mr Ripper" don't sound right.

Comment: You might want to provide a few more details about your dialect since some BrE users find this usage strange and it conflicts with the top rated answer at the moment.

Comment: I have never heard it used in the Home Counties, but it may be in use somewhere.

Comment: N. London middle class, I don't know what you'd call that formally.

Comment: I have heard "died due to cancer" but not " died to cancer" myself. But that does not mean it's not a local variation.